# How to use ngModel for two different scenarios

Tags: angular

I want to use a select for two different ways:

First (The Object exists) -> I want to show the selected Object in a select and I want to be able to change the Object

Second (The Object does not exist) -> I want to select a Object

This is the code of the Object:

```
export class Brand {
    brandId: number;
    name: string;

    constructor() {}
}
```

What I need is the following (1) to show the selected Brand in the select with ngModel and that the ngModel is correct (I will explan it with the following code)

This Code would give me a correct Brand Object (with brandId and name) but it will not show me the current selected Brand in the select

```
<div class="from-group">
        <label>Marke</label>
        <select name="brand" [(ngModel)]="phone.brand" class="browser-default custom-select" (selectionChange)="brandChanged($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let brand of allBrands" [ngValue]="brand">{{brand.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

---

This Code will give me a incorrect Brand Object (just the name but no ID) but it will show me the current selected Brand in the select

```
<div class="from-group">
      <label>Marke</label>
      <select name="brand" [(ngModel)]="phone.brand.name" class="browser-default custom-select" (selectionChange)="brandChanged($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let brand of allBrands" [value]="brand.name">{{brand.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

How do I have to change my code that I can set the current selected Brand to the select (and show no Brand if there is no Brand selected) AND get the correct Brand Object from the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your object and the object in the array have no reference, Angular cannot set the value for you. But you can use `compareWith`, which compares the objects and returns `true` if the objects match:

```html
<select name="brand" [(ngModel)]="phone.brand" [compareWith]="compareFn">
  <option *ngFor="let brand of allBrands" [ngValue]="brand">{{brand.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The function:

```ts
compareFn(b1: Brand, b2: Brand): boolean {
  return b1 && b2 ? b1.brandId === b2.brandId : b1 === b2;
}
```

DEMO: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edjaea)**